# Using a foreign key in dropdown in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreign-key-relationship

I'm new to MVC, and stuck on what should be a pretty straight forward issue.  I'm working through [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) and got everything pretty much working, except I now want to add a foreign key 'link' (not sure what it's called) but can't seem to get it to work.  Here's what I have:

Tables:

```
 Inventory:
 Id   |  SerialNumber  | ManufacturerId (foreignkey to Manufactueres->id)

 Manufactureres
 Id (primary key)   |  Name
```

Model (InventoryItem.cs):

```
 public class InventoryItem {
     public int Id {get; set; }
     public int SerialNumber{ get; set; }

     //this starts the trouble, I actually want to interact with the Manufactureres table -> Name column
     public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }  
 }
```

View (Create.cshtml):

```
 ...
 //What i really want is a dropdown of the values in the Manufactureres table
 @Html.EditorFor(model=> model.ManufacturerId)
```

This must be a farely common issue when using a relational database there would be many foreign key relationships to be used/shown, but for some reason i can't find a tutorial or issue on stackoverflow that directly corresponds to something so simple.  Any guidance, or direction is much appreciated!
Thanks,

Comment: Thanks @BrendanVogt, I actually ended up using the "ViewBag" method (I think), having found a perfect example here: [http://bit.ly/VCOyah] which fit my needs, and was simple enough for me to follow.  I think I just need to read more to understand the "viewmodel" method, and to understand entityframework better to implement your solution.  But since your answer was very complete, and recommended by others, i'm glad to mark it, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly.  Seems like when you want to add a new inventory item then you want a list of all the manufacturers in a dropdown list.  I am going to work on this assumption, please let me know if I am off the track :)

Firstly go and create a view model.  This view model you will bind to yout view.  Never bind domain objects to your view.

```
public class InventoryItemViewModel
{
     public int SerialNumber { get; set; }

     public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
}
```

Your domain objects:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int SerialNumber{ get; set; }

     public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller might look like this:

```
public class InventoryItemController : Controller
{
     private readonly IManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository;
     private readonly IInventoryItemRepository inventoryItemRepository;

     public InventoryItem(IManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository, IManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository)
     {
          // Check that manufacturerRepository and inventoryItem are not null

          this.manufacturerRepository = manufacturerRepository;
          this.inventoryItemRepository = inventoryItemRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
          InventoryItemViewModel viewModel = new InventoryItemViewModel
          {
               Manufacturers = manufacturerRepository.GetAll()
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(InventoryItemViewModel viewModel)
     {
          // Check that viewModel is not null

          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {
               Manufacturers = manufacturerRepository.GetAll()

               return View(viewModel);
          }

          // All validation is cool

          // Use a mapping tool like AutoMapper
          // to map between view model and domain model
          InventoryItem inventoryItem = Mapper.Map<InventoryItem>(viewModel);

          inventoryItemRepository.Insert(inventoryItem);

          // Return to which ever view you need to display
          return View("List");
     }
}
```

And then in your view you might have the following:

```
@model MyProject.DomainModel.ViewModels.InventoryItems.InventoryItemViewModel

<table>
     <tr>
          <td class="edit-label">Serial Number <span class="required">**</span></td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SerialNumber, new { maxlength = "10" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SerialNumber)
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td class="edit-label">Manufacturer <span class="required">**</span></td>
          <td>
               @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    x => x.ManufacturerId,
                    new SelectList(Model.Manufacturers, "Id", "Name", Model.ManufacturerId),
                    "-- Select --"
               )
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ManufacturerId)
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, a couple questions (sorry newbie):

1. why a "View Model"?  I already have a model of InventoryITem with manufacturerId?  Or are you suggesting I have 1 model, which is a 'view model' which combines both the Inventory items, and the manufacturer id?

2. Is it really necessary to install a plugin like AutoMapper just to achieve this? it seems like referencing a foreign key table like this would be so common, there would be already be mechanisms to achieve it. Sorry, again newbie, just want to keep it as simple as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: A model might have a lot of properties. A view model contains only the properties that you need on your view. View model might contain data from multiple domain models.

Comment: You don't have to use AutoMapper. You van do your own mapping. It maps your properties in about 2 lines of  code. Can you imagine if you have to map between 20 properties how much code you have to write?

Comment: Really appreciate the help.  Trying your code. what are the `IInventoryItemRepository` and `IManufacturerRepository` items you have?  I'm getting errors that they don't exist, and that there's not `GetAll()` method for them.

Comment: How do you get your data from the database?

Comment: Look at my profile and make contact and I will send you code over the weekend.

Comment: For completeness: I'm using "entityframework" as outlined in this tutorial here [http://bit.ly/VCQzDn].  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is common issue, you need select `Manufactureres` in action and then send them to view. You can use `ViewBag` or strontly typed view model.

**Examples:**

- [Problem populating dropdown boxes in an ASP.NET MVC 3
  Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869009/problem-populating-dropdown-boxes-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-application)
- [Having difficulty using an ASP.NET MVC ViewBag and
  DropDownListfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377402/having-difficulty-using-an-asp-net-mvc-viewbag-and-dropdownlistfor)
- [MVC3 Razor @Html.DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070762/mvc3-razor-html-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: Thanks those are helpful to some extent, but still looking for some simple examples of what to do for the Views/Create and Views/Edit which are giving me the most trouble.  If you think of any other tutorials or examples, please send them my way. Thanks!

Comment: My solution does what you are looking for.

Comment: @russds This is done like I posted, also **Brendan Vogt** example looks nice. `AutoMapper` used just for filling class.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would recommend you.

1) Create a Manufacturer model class

```
public class Manufacturer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create InventoryItem model class as follows

```
public class InventoryItem
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int SerialNumber{ get; set; }

     public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Id ")]
public Manufacturer Manufacturer{get; set;}

public IEnumerable<Manufacturer> Manufacturer {get;set;}

}
```

3) Make sure DbContext is also updated as follows

```
public DbSet<InventoryItem> InventoryItem {get;set;}
public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturer{get;set;}
```

4) Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            InventoryItem model = new InventoryItem();
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                model.Manufacturer= new SelectList(db.Manufacturer.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(InventoryItem  model)
        {
            //Check the Model State
            if(! ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    model.Manufacturer= new SelectList(db.Manufacturer.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                InventoryItem  dto = new InventoryItem();
                dto.SerialNumber= model.SerialNumber;
                dto.Id= model.Id;

                Manufacturer manudto = db.Manufacturer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id== model.Id);
                dto.CatName = manudto.CatName;

                db.Test.Add(dto);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
                TempData["SM"] = "Added";

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

5) Make sure View has dropdownselect option in below format

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Manufacturer,"Select", new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope this works :D